# Change content of the default email received for validation email in azure b2c - custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to customize the default template of the default verification email sent by azure for email validation when signing up or forgotting password?

if yes, how to do it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the default email sending mechanism, you can only customize banner logo, background color, email signature and nothing else:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#how-do-i-customize-verification-emails--the-content-and-the--from---field--sent-by-azure-ad-b2c-

You can also completely customize your email using third party email providers such as SendGrid, but this requires additional infrastructure and custom policies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy